# How to reward for two parameters in reinforcement learning?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch

I have a two box that should touch each other in straight line, so I have done two approach to reward:

Approach 1: Reward when distance is decreasing
this approach works well in 50% event after 100 million steps of training. The problem is that two box do not touch each other completely straight and it fails in 50%

Approach 2  Reward when distance is decreasing and radius difference between two box is decreasing
So here is the methods

```
if(distance < lastDistance)
  AddReward(...)
  lastDistance = distance;

if(radius < lastRadius )
  AddReward(...)
  lastRadius = radius;
```

The problem with approach 2 is that the box 1 which is moving is only rotating after a 10 million steps and even not decreasing distance

So How can I reward for multi parameters (distance, radius) problems

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try to use only the first way and improve it.

You can add more conditions to help your agent to reach the goal.

for example :

```
reward = 0

if(distance < lastDistance)
  reward += 1
  lastDistance = distance

if(distance < 5)
  reward += 5

if(distance < 3)
  reward += 10
```

PS : the values are chosen randomly. Change them to reach the goal you want.